# Transform:rotate not just rotates but also translates

Tags: css, rotation

I am learning CSS transitions and transformations. here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Transformatons and Transitions</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/n.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="animate">animate</div>
    <div class="animate">animate2</div>
    <div class="different">different1</div>
    <div class="different">different2</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS is:

```
div.different {
    transform: translate(1000px,400px);
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    transition:1s ease-in-out;
}
div.different:hover{
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg);    
}
```

The rotate is not working properly. instead of just rotating, the element is moving back the original place it was. Instead of staying at (1000px,400px) the element is going back to (0px,0px)
How do I prevent its moving?

Comment: Are you trying to rotate from the original position or the new position?

Comment: On a side note, I recommend not using div.different, instead just use .different for your selector, it is more useful and faster for the browser to understand and apply. There might be a case tomorrow where you need to use this class in a different tag than div.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `translate` on `hover` too because browser interpret your hover transform as `translate(0,0) rotate(300deg)`:

```
div.different {
  -webkit-transform: translate(1000px, 400px);
      -ms-transform: translate(1000px, 400px);
          transform: translate(1000px, 400px);
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: block;
  width: 125px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}
div.different:hover {
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transform: translate(1000px, 400px) rotate(300deg);
      -ms-transform: translate(1000px, 400px) rotate(300deg);
          transform: translate(1000px, 400px) rotate(300deg);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you explain that this happens because he is overriding the transform css property by defining transform again, that's why he needs to  specify both in hover.

Answer (score 2):

Define both transformations in the same statement and change them accordingly:

```
div.different {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(1000px,400px);
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    transition:1s ease-in-out;
}
div.different:hover{
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translate(1000px,400px);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/quvLtwjt/1/

You were overriding the previous transform.

---

**But**, if you want to rotate the `div` from the **current** position and not the old position then you need to use `transform-origin` to redefine the new position and put both transformations in the same statement:

```
   div.different {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(1000px,400px);
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    transition:1s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 1000px 400px;
}
div.different:hover{
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) translate(1000px,400px);
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/quvLtwjt/